# Error with JQuery Script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I developed the below image changer with JQuery:

```
var images = [];
images[0] = "image1.jpg";
images[1] = "image2.jpg";

var i = 0;
setInterval(fadeDivs, 3000);

function fadeDivs() {
    i = i < images.length ? i : 0;
    $('.slideshow-right-corner img').fadeOut(100, function(){
        $(this).attr('src', images[i]).fadeIn(100);
    })
    i++;
}
```

For some reason, it works fine locally, however when I integrate with my website, it works fine for the first image in the array and stops working. The following is the error I receive when I inspect the element:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (index):398 (anonymous
>   function) (index):398 E.complete jquery-1.3.2.min.js?ver=3.4.1:19
>   o.fx.step jquery-1.3.2.min.js?ver=3.4.1:19 F
>   jquery-1.3.2.min.js?ver=3.4.1:19 (anonymous function)

Comment: What are the differences between your live and test environment? Same versions of jQuery and any other plugins etc?

Comment: have all the script include correctly?

Comment: Needles to say, jQuery 1.3.2 is really, really old (~5 years, 2009).

Comment: use latest jquery if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Working JSBIN DEMO](http://jsbin.com/lujud/1/edit)

```
function fadeDivs() {
  $.each(images, function(e) {
     $('.slideshow-right-corner img').fadeOut(100,    function(){
        $(this).attr('src', images[e]).fadeIn(100);
    });
 });
}
```

You can remove the i variable outside the function.

Comment: The demo is not working. Try to use different images (and not the same one repeated) and only only will be displayed.

Comment: What's the reason for doing `var self = e;`? Just use `images[e]`, much simpler.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is multithreading. The `i++` will be evaluated before the fadeOut function.

So when i=2 `images[2]` will return undefined and the program will stop working.

Try to move `i++` inside the function, after fading in.

This is the updated code (TESTED):

```
function fadeDivs() {
   i = i < images.length ? i : 0;
   $('.slideshow-right-corner img').fadeOut(100, function() {
   $(this).attr('src', images[i]).fadeIn(100);
   i++;
});
```

Comment: and i = i < images.length ? i : 0; as well while you're at it

Answer (score 0):

As @Stefano Altieri said, the `i` variable is increased before the ending of the `fadeIn` function. Replace the `fadeDivs` function with this:

```
function fadeDivs() {
    i = i < images.length ? i : 0;
    $('.slideshow-right-corner img').fadeOut(100, function(){
        $(this).attr('src', images[i]).fadeIn(100, function(){
            i++;
        });
    })
}
```